# Como criar uma identação personalizada no visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Olá. Gostaria de saber como faz para o visual studio code não idente de forma diferente da que eu quero na hora de salvar.
Eu quero assim:

```
function classificaIMC(imc) 

{

}
```

Mas ele identa assim:

```
function classificaIMC(imc) {

}
```

Eu quero essa identação pra todos os códigos, tanto para C# quanto para javascript e html...

Comment: Tenta desabilitar qualquer coisa de identação que vc tenha instalado e configurado. Normalmente a identação não muda quando se salva o arquivo, a não ser que vc tenha mudado algo na configuração padrão, ou instalado algum plugin/extensão

Comment: E como se faz isso?

Comment: Você não terá ativado a indentação quando salva ? Isso é feito colocando `"editor.formatOnSave": true` no `settings.json`